# Syntax error in different version of Postgres

Tags: postgresql, syntax

Following statement

```
insert into abc.ad_campaign as ac (client_id, acquisio_id, name) 
values (356619, 5356522, 'Massage - Hand & Stone') 
ON CONFLICT(client_id, acquisio_id) 
DO UPDATE SET name = EXCLUDED.name;
```

giving syntax error at or near "as" in version Postgres 9.4.6 and PSQL version 9.6.3. Same query running fine in other version

Comment: The ability to specify an alias was introduced in 9.5 so obviously this won't work in 9.4. And both versions (9.6 and 9.4) are no longer supported or maintained and you shouldn't be using them to begin with.

Comment: Additionally - the alias in this particular query is not used and hence its specifying makes no sense.